# Redis connection errors on high load environment

Tags: python, redis, centos, centos7, python-3.8

I'm working on a very heavy load environment,

I have python code that starts a process pool of 300 processes on a server that has around 100 CPUs, and constantly runs processes that checks Redis for a value, if that value doesn't exist, it saves it and if it does, it runs some heavy calculations. it does so using the Redis `get set` command.

each process has a Redis client that is being initialized only once, and then used through the program

pseudo code

```py
import redis
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

redis: redis.Redis

def init_process():

    global redis
    redis = redis.Redis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, decode_response=True)

def recieved_request(unique_id):
    x = redis.getset(unique_id, "hello world")
    if x is not None:
        heavy_cpu_load()
        redis.delete(unique_id)
    else:
        redis.expire(unique_id, 60)

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=300, initializer=init_process)



def on_new_request():
    pool.submit(recieved_request)
```

when running the code with low traffic it works as expected but when running on high traffic I get the following errors:

`error 99 - connecting to cannot assign requested address`

`error while reading from 127.0.0.1:6379: (104, connection is reset by peer)`

`connection is closed by server`

I've tried messing with the timeout in order to quickly close idle connections, and changing the amount of `maxconnection` to 50000, both lead to no changes in the behaviour.

- when running the same code without heavy CPU calculation I get no errors
- I cannot run Redis on a different machine.
- I'm using the latest Redis available (7.0.11) on centos7.8 and python3.8.10

Comment: First (and this may be not the problem for your case) the GETSET command seems to be deprecated as per these docs: https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.getset

I could be wrong, but the problem with connections could arise because you create a connection, and then share it among 300 processes. That may cause some racing conditions. I am not 100% sure about that. 

Instead, I would recommend to establish a connection inside each process individually. Redis should handle 300 connections without problems.